# Testing a csv file import/upload in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am really just starting using ruby on rails and rspec, and I have to test that a file is able to be uploaded and displayed on the web page through automation.  The user should hit the choose file button and be able to get a .csv file and upload it, so I am looking to either generate a file or just use one of the example ones I have and have that done automatically.

As I said, I am really new to this whole thing and I am working as part of a QA team, so any help is appreciated.  I dont know what code I need to supply, and I really dont have an idea of what to do.  Ive searched google and cannot make sense of most of the results, so I don't really have any useful code written so far.

Tell me any code which I would need to supply, as I assume something is necessary.  I am using rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the cucumber + capybara (yes, they use rspec) combination would be perfect for what you need. Here is a quick tutorial on how it's done: http://cassiomarques.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/how-to-test-file-uploads-with-cucumber/.

Comment: Ah!! Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Couldnt seem to find it through my searches, thanks a lot